# How to pass variable from one method to another in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

Please, I need help, I know that this is basic oop but I'm still learning...

```
public function confirm()
{
    $q = Input::get('track');
    $confirm = Tracking::where(function ($query) use ($q) {
      $query->where('tracking_no', 'like',  $q );
  })->first();

    if ($confirm) {
        return Redirect::to('progress');
    } else if(!$confirm){
        return Redirect::to('invalid-tracking-number');
    }

}

public function invalid($q)
{
   $data =  $this->confirm($q);
    return view('frontend.invalid');
}
```

I'm to pass the input field from confirm() to invalid() but is not working... I need the  `$q` inside my `invalid()`
so that I pass it to view...

Comment: You shouldn't learn OOP with Laravel as it is a behemoth. Consider learning OOP by experimenting with your own custom frameworks. Use Laravel to learn Laravel. To answer your question, it should involve simply [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)ing the data you want from that function.

Comment: I don't see where you are using the invalid method...

Comment: check the code, I have confirm(){ $q = Input::get('track') } and I want to use the $q inside invalid(){}

Comment: @Legendary yes... but no... Where are you actually calling `invalid`?

Comment: @Script47 invalid() is inside my method...

Comment: Yes but where is it called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it....I reference another method using

```
 if($confirm->isNotEmpty())
 { 
   return (a valid page)
 } else {
   return $this->invalid();
 }
```

with is, I'm able to return all the input data to the view of invalid